# why I can't open any port when I deploy my django on my server, but my test program can run on my own machine

Tags: python, django, web

I'm learning django to make a test website, I can run the site on my own laptop, and use the browser to visit 127.0.0.1 , it's ok

but when I do the same thing on my server, I bought a vps and a domain,  I just can't telnet the port , the browser also can't connect, I don't know why

I do the following

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

on my laptop, 8080 port can be connected by telnet, but on my server , it can't

Comment: are you sure nothing else is using port `8080` ? what error message do you get ?

Comment: no, I use netstat anx| grep 8080, and there is not any entry

Comment: why are you even using development server, see @DanielRoseman's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Two things.

Firstly, as the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) explains, by default runserver only binds to the localhost interface, which means it is only available on a browser running on the same machine. To get it to be visible outside the local machine, you need to bind to an externally-visible address, or 0.0.0.0 for all addresses:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Secondly, as the documentation also explains, you should not be trying to use the development server in a production setting anyway. Use a proper webserver, eg Apache + mod_wsgi.